# Flutter Series<T, D> constructor

Tags: android, flutter, dart, charts

I encountered following snippet of code when trying to plot data using flutter chart library.

```
_getSeriesData() {
    List<charts.Series<PopulationData, String>> series = [
      charts.Series(
        id: "Population",
        data: data,
        domainFn: (PopulationData series, _) => series.year.toString(),
        measureFn: (PopulationData series, _) => series.population,
        colorFn: (PopulationData series, _) => series.barColor
      )
    ];
    return series;
}
```

I am struggling to understand the code, especially the following lines.

```
    domainFn: (PopulationData series, _) => series.year.toString(),
    measureFn: (PopulationData series, _) => series.population,
    colorFn: (PopulationData series, _) => series.barColor
```

I don't know how the charts. Series represent the data. I can't find any tutorials on the 'Series' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Series` is a wrapper class around list of 'points' - easiest to think of [x,y] pairs - *together with* a handful of functions that know how to interpret/format those [x,y] points into (normally) strings. The `data` member of the series is the list of these points; the `xxxFn` members are the functions.

What can get a bit confusing is that these points are represented by an arbitrary class (in your case `PopulationData`), not by, say, a pair of ints (one for x, one for y). So, `charts` has no way of knowing how to interpret a `PopulationData` unless you tell it. That's the purpose of the helper functions you provide.

`measureFn` is a function that takes a `PopulationData` and returns the 'y' axis variable. `domainFn` is the same for the 'x' axis variable. (The second parameter is `index`, in case you need to know which point/bar is being rendered.)

The current code is *particularly* difficult to understand as the author has overloaded the word `series`, where it may make more sense to use `pd` meaning "an instance of a population data", and that these are functions that return the relevant part of the instance.

Rewrite it as:

```
    domainFn: (PopulationData pd, _) => pd.year.toString(),
    measureFn: (PopulationData pd, _) => pd.population,
    colorFn: (PopulationData pd, _) => pd.barColor,
```

to see more easily that `year`, `population` and `barColor` are members of `PopulationData`.

Also, see a [simple example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/simple) in the charts examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me, what is the '_" in (PopulationData pd, _) mean?

Comment: It's just an unused parameter.

Comment: The signature of that function is `typedef TypedAccessorFn<T, R> = R Function(T datum, int index);` Since none of these functions makes use of the `index` parameter it's given the name `-` to indicate that it's ignored.